# Log sql-queries agains local sql-express instance

Tags: logging, sql-server-express

Is there a way to log all queries against the local sql-express instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the tools for tha evaluation of SQl Server and the DB for SQL Server Express and then use Profiler to log all the queries made against the Express instance.

Check [this](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2010/08/05/setting-up-sql-server-2008-express-with-profiler/) out.